# Hover to Switch Images Glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"></div>    
<div id="coming-soon"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logo").hover(
        function(){
            $("#logo").fadeTo(300, 0);
            $("#coming-soon").fadeTo(300, 1.0);
        },
        function(){
            $("#logo").fadeTo(300, 1.0); 
            $("#coming-soon").fadeTo(300, 0); 
        });
});
```

Right now the `#logo` element fades out on hover and `#coming-soon` fades in, and vice versa when the mouse is taken off the element (which is exactly what I want), but mousing over the new element that's faded in (the "Coming Soon" text) makes the old element fade in, when I don't want it to fade back in until the mouse is no longer over the same area.

My question is how can I modify my code so hovering over the `#coming-soon` element doesn't make the original element fade back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `#coming-soon`'s z-index to `-1` (or give `#logo` a higher z-index).

Also, use `.stop()` before your `fadeTo()`s:

```
$("#logo").hover(
    function(){
        $("#logo").stop().fadeTo(300, 0);
        $("#coming-soon").stop().fadeTo(300, 1.0);
    },
    function(){
        $("#logo").stop().fadeTo(300, 1.0); 
        $("#coming-soon").stop().fadeTo(300, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give `#logo` a higher z-index than `#coming-soon` in your CSS.

```
#logo{ z-index: 1; } 
#coming-soon{ z-index: 0; }
```

Comment: @DannyCooper: I took a look at your website, and if you hover on and off the image repeatedly, the animation queue builds up. To stop this, you can just use `.stop()` before the `fadeTo()`, like I said in my answer.

Comment: @Purmou Thanks, I didn't realize it had that problem. I tried the code you suggested and for some reason the hover effect doesn't work on my first hover. I have to take my mouse off and hover a 2nd time to activate the effect. Any ideas?

Comment: @DannyCooper: It should [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/QQuw3/show/). You want to email me so I can help you further?

Comment: Got it, thanks for the demo. I had my JS at the end of my <body> element and I think it wasn't loading fast enough. I put it in the <head> and everything works perfect now.